# Reaching class method (function inside the class) in React

Tags: reactjs, function, class

everyone.
I'm trying to write a simple program which will cause word 'Hi' appearing on the screen.
Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {
    Hi = () => {
        return <h1>Hi</h1>
    }
    state = {
        showSayHi: false
    }
    sayHi = () => {                                                    
        this.setState({                                               
            showSayHi: true
        }) ;                                                                          
    }  
    render() {
        const { showSayHi } = this.state;       
        return (
            <div>
               {this.state.showSayHi ? Hi() : null}
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.sayHi}>Press me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Button;
ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

There is the version that Hi function is not globally defined, but I don't know how to define the function globally.
Problem seems to be lying in Hi function or in its call inside ternary operator.
Can anyone please help me to get this thing working?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot **this.**

Here:

```
{this.state.showSayHi ? this.Hi() : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your methods by this.methodName inside a class components.
`{this.state.showSayHi ? this.Hi() : null}`

Define Hi as a functional component.

```
function Hi(props) {
  return(
    <h1>Hi !</h1>
  )
}
```

To use this component globally, move this code to a file and then import Hi by exporting this code from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please make it this.Hi() in this.state.showSayHi ? Hi() : null

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is to get Hi to appear on the screen there's no need for two components:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { showHi: false };

  showHi = () => this.setState({ showHi: !this.state.showHi });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.showHi ? 'Hi' : null}
          <button onClick={this.showHi}>Toggle Hi</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution appart from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336734/12100520)

You can keep Hi() without this:

```
{this.state.showSayHi ? Hi() : null}
```

But, to keep it that way, then you have to get the function Hi() out of the class. Like this:

```
const Hi = () => {
    return <h1>Hi</h1>
}

class Button extends React.Component {
state = {
    showSayHi: false
}
sayHi = () => {                                                    
    this.setState({                                               
        showSayHi: true
    }) ;                                                                          
}  
render() {
    const { showSayHi } = this.state;       
    return (
        <div>
           {this.state.showSayHi ? Hi() : null}
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.sayHi}>Press me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I do not encourage you to do that (unless you want to use also the function Hi() out of the class). I just want to show you that this solution also works. If you compare it with the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336734/12100520), you will understand how the word **this** works within a class.